# Syntax near AS however I can not identify the problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I keep getting the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.

I cannot see the problem.

```
use leads;

select *
    (select max(HighTrw) 
     from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) as Value (HighTrw)) as [high_trw]
from 
    dbo.spi s
Where 
    (select max(HighTrw)
     from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)) between '600' and '625'
```

Comment: That query is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: To start, select space asterisk comma `select *,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sort of looks like SQL Server code, so I will use that syntax.

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
select s.*, ss.high_trw
from dbo.spi s outer apply
     (select max(Value.HighTrw) as high_trw
      from (values (s.trw1), (s.trw2), (s.trw21)
           ) as Value(HighTrw)
     ) ss
where ss.high_trw between 600 and 625;
```

Notes:

- You can put the subquery into the `from` clause using `apply`.
- One obvious problem is the lack of comma before the correlated subquery.
- You should learn to qualify *all* column names.  This is especially important for correlated subqueries.
- `600` and `625` look like numbers, not strings.  If so, the constants should not have quotes.

Comment: Yes sorry SQL server is the dbms. The missing , did the trick thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things concern me about your code, apart from not supplying some data:

```
use leads;

-- There's no comma "," after the "*"
select*
-- This look like it belongs in the "from" section as a subquery, eg "(select ...) as sub"
-- You can then reference all of its contents in the main select using "sub.*"
(select max(HighTrw) from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) as Value(HighTrw)) as [high_trw]


from dbo.spi s

Where (select max(HighTrw)
-- Haven't seen this way of specifying a table before, is it valid? 
-- Why not explicitly define a temporary table above with the data you want, _before_ starting the query? - makes the code cleaner/clearer, IMO
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (trw21)) As updatedate (HighTrw)) between '600' and '625'
-- There's no final ";" to terminate the query, might not be absolutely necessary, but good habit, 
-- because at some point, this code's going to dovetail into some other code, and the compiler will probably throw a wobbly
```